# How to get username Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to get catch tagged username in reply. below code sends Dm to user when we tag them example `?hello @Steve`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await bot.send_message(member, "Hi (username) how are you.")
```

bot reply's `Hi Steve how are you.`

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking here. What have you tried so far? What is a "Tagged username"?

Comment: `await bot.send_message(member, "Hi {} how are you.".format(member.name))` should do it. You can see the docs for `User` (which is the parent class of `Member`) [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User).

Comment: @L3viathan  yes its worked perfect.

Comment: I would use [`member.display_name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.display_name) instead.  That gets the server-specific nickname if available, but falls back to the username otherwise.

Comment: yes both worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check [User](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User)
Example:

```
await bot.send_message(member, "Hi {} I love ya.".format(member.name))
```